# Finding the average of R table object

Tags: r, average

Other questions using "table" in their title are actually using data frame.

I want to keep this **strictly about `table` object**.

Suppose I have tables with same structure that I want to find the average of.

For example:

```
test1 <- head(table(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species))

(test1 + test1 + test1) / 3

> (test1 + test1 + test1) / 3
     
      setosa versicolor virginica
  4.3      1          0         0
  4.4      3          0         0
  4.5      1          0         0
  4.6      4          0         0
  4.7      2          0         0
  4.8      5          0         0
```

However, it cannot be done by:

```
> mean(c(test1,test1,test1))
[1] 0.8888889
> sum(c(test1,test1,test1)) / 3
[1] 16
```

Best approach I could find was to make the objects into a list of tables and use `Reduce` function:

```
Reduce(`+`, list(test1, test1, test1)) / 3
```

Is there more simpler way to do it without going back and forth using `list` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may loop over the `array` in the 1st two dimensions and get the `mean`

```
apply(replicate(3, test1), 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
       setosa versicolor virginica
  4.3      1          0         0
  4.4      3          0         0
  4.5      1          0         0
  4.6      4          0         0
  4.7      2          0         0
  4.8      5          0         0
```

---

Or loop over a single dimension and get the `rowMeans/colMeans`

```
apply(replicate(3, test1), 2, rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
     
      setosa versicolor virginica
  4.3      1          0         0
  4.4      3          0         0
  4.5      1          0         0
  4.6      4          0         0
  4.7      2          0         0
  4.8      5          0         0
```

Both these methods are better than the `Reduce` approach with `+` especially when there are missing values as `na.rm` argument is found in both `mean` and `rowMeans/colMeans`

NOTE: `replicate` is used to create an `array` by replicating the object 'test1' `n` times.

---

If the object is already a `list` of `table`s, then convert to `array` with `simplify2array` before applying the `apply`

```
apply(simplify2array(list(test1, test1, test1)), 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
     
      setosa versicolor virginica
  4.3      1          0         0
  4.4      3          0         0
  4.5      1          0         0
  4.6      4          0         0
  4.7      2          0         0
  4.8      5          0         0
```